# Deserializing XML does not fill inner objects

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd

I am trying to deserialize a xml based on an xsd for this xsd.exe to generate the class structure below is the part of the class generated

```
public partial class tsResponse {

    private object[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("credentials", typeof(credentialsType), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}


    /// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]

public partial class credentialsType {

    private credentialsTypeSite siteField;

    private object userField;

    private string nameField;

    private string passwordField;

    private string tokenField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public credentialsTypeSite site {
        get {
            return this.siteField;
        }
        set {
            this.siteField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public object user {
        get {
            return this.userField;
        }
        set {
            this.userField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string password {
        get {
            return this.passwordField;
        }
        set {
            this.passwordField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string token {
        get {
            return this.tokenField;
        }
        set {
            this.tokenField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

But now when I try to deserialize the below XML the credetial type is not populated in the items array

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <tsResponse xmlns="http://tableausoftware.com/api" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tableausoftware.com/api http://tableausoftware.com/api/ts-api-2.0.xsd">
      <credentials token="79ec436cc643dda259184206b966d5bf">
        <site contentUrl=""/>
      </credentials>
     </tsResponse>
```

I don't understand why this is  happening, please help.

Comment: If you serialize using BinaryFormatter or SoapFormatter, then every field whether it is public or private will be serialized.  If you serialize using XmlSerializer then only public fields or private fields exposed by public properties will be serialized.

Comment: Perhaps you would find this link helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx